# Existing Wordpress extension/plugin to let users sell their courses (like Udemy)?

Tags: wordpress

Is there a WordPress extension/plugin that allows users to sell their courses on a website. Just like Udemy but more simple...

It would be a type of plateform that specific users (pro) could use to create and purpose their own courses to basic users.

I found a lot of LMS Extensions but it's only to sell our proper courses and make subscriptions on them.

It's just to know if something is existing or if I need to develop specifically.

Thanks for your anwser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LearnDash is one of the best. You don't need to have it as a subscription based product. You can use WooCommerce and set up a course product to sell. Doesn't have to be on amembership basis. Here is an article for more information:

https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/create-course-marketplace-learndash/